# Bind .sdf query to listbox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, sql-server-ce

Can anyone help me with this problem i want to bind the following results.

```
 public IList<bankingCategory> bankingInfo()
    {
        IList<bankingCategory> bankList = null;
        using (dataContext context = new dataContext(globalInfo.strConnectionString))
        {
            IQueryable<bankingCategory> query = from c in context.bankcategorees select c;
            bankList = query.ToList();

        }

        return bankList;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

set item source from code behind

```
MyListBox.ItemsSource =bankingInfo();
```

You need to set customize your list box template like below

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox Name="MyListBox">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Property1}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Property2}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>               
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: It worked but what if i want to use multiple IList from different tables?